# Historic Join on Dates

Tags: sql

i have the following code which gets all the historic data from the two tables,
  this part of code is present in my query whihc is quite big,and this particular part is taking quite long time to excute even though i have index in it .

```
select B.PER,MAX(B.BGDT,C.BGDT) AS BGDT
              , MIN(B.ENDT,C.ENDT) AS ENDT,B.BGDT as  begb,C.BGDT as begc,B.ENDT as endb,C.ENDT as endc from PERDET B, PER C where  ( C.BGDT >= B.BGDT
                 AND C.BGDT <= B.ENDT
                )
                OR
                (
                     B.BGDT >= C.BGDT
                 AND B.BGDT <= C.ENDT
                )
```

;

Is there any other way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT B.PER, MAX(B.EFCV_BGDT,C.EFCV_BGDT) AS EFCV_BGDT, 
       MIN(B.EFCV_ENDT,C.EFCV_ENDT) AS EFCV_ENDT, B.EFCV_BGDT as  begb, 
       C.EFCV_BGDT as begc,B.EFCV_ENDT as endb, C.EFCV_ENDT as endc 
       FROM PERDET B, PER C 
       WHERE ( C.EFCV_BGDT >= B.EFCV_BGDT
             OR C.EFCV_BGDT <= B.EFCV_ENDT
            )
            AND
            (
                 B.EFCV_BGDT >= C.EFCV_BGDT
             OR B.EFCV_BGDT <= C.EFCV_ENDT
            )
```

Because the conditions you are giving will nevber be matched which are :-

```
(B.EFCV_BGDT >= C.EFCV_BGDT AND B.EFCV_BGDT <= C.EFCV_ENDT)
```

Beacuse one value can never be grater than and less than at the same with another value.

Comment: am not understanding what your saying me to try ankit

Comment: What @user3248637 is saying is "examine your logic." The effect of "a>=b and a<=b" is equivalent to "a=b" so your entire where clause shortens to "where C.BGDT = B.BGDT". Since you are looking only at rows where these two fields are equal, that calls into question the use of Min and Max. So its a really good bet the query is not returning what you want it to.

Comment: What @Rafs is saying is that you are joining every row of the two tables based only on the date field. There is almost certainly some other criteria that relates a row of one table to a matching row in the other table. Join on that criteria first and then on how the dates relate (once you straighten out how that might be). My only suggestion would be to join on the id *and* the dates rather than join all the rows on id and then filter out based on date.

Answer (score 0):

Does the PER and PERDET have a common ID that links the two tables?
I can't tell how the tables are related without maybe a screen shot of some sample data of the first 100 rows or so, but if there is a common ID (which I'll use as cid) you could try this:

```
SELECT B.PER,MAX(B.EFCV_BGDT,C.EFCV_BGDT) AS EFCV_BGDT
    , MIN(B.EFCV_ENDT,C.EFCV_ENDT) AS EFCV_ENDT
    ,B.EFCV_BGDT as  begb
    ,C.EFCV_BGDT as begc
    ,B.EFCV_ENDT as endb
    ,C.EFCV_ENDT as endc 
    FROM PERDET B
    INNER JOIN PER C ON B.cid = C.cid
    WHERE  ( C.EFCV_BGDT BETWEEN B.EFCV_BGDT
        AND B.EFCV_ENDT
    )
    OR
    (
            B.EFCV_BGDT BETWEEN C.EFCV_BGDT
        AND C.EFCV_ENDT
    )
```

I don't know if that will speed things up for you or not.